Bitbucket merge issues
I was trying to merge release branch into develop branch in bitbucket. For this when I am creating pull request it's not allowing me to create one, saying develop is already up to date.
But I know for sure there are lot of differences between these two branches, also I have verified manually that there are differences.
Also I did below:
git clone https://...
git checkout develop
git diff release

I could see the differences. Now how should I bring those changes from release to develop and why is bitbucket not able to catch those changes?
This all happened because previously when release was merged in develop is was done using ours strategy and hence though commits  were merged from release to develop but the actual changes were not merged.
When I create PR from develop to release it shows a lot of changes.
What would be the cleanest way to bring all changes from release to develop branch here?

How do you try to create a pull request?

@mkrieger1 Using Bitbucket UI console

What do you type/click/select there?

There is link in UI to create Pull request where we have to specify source & target, I am using that. I hope i answered your question

And what do you select as source and target?

source is release branch & target is develop branch

What happens if you choose develop as source and release as target?

When you did git clone https://..., did you clone from Bitbucket or from somewhere else?

I cloned from bitbucket same repository

If you do git checkout develop and then git status, and then git checkout release and then git status, does it say that both your local branches are up-to-date with the remote branches, or does it say that one of your branches is ahead or behind the remote branch?

local branches are up to date with remote

Okay, then I'm out of ideas what could be the reason that Bitbucket won't let you create a pull request.

git status does not connect to the remote, so if something has changed on the remote since cloning then you'll need to run either git fetch or git pull to get the newest stuff.

Can you show a git log release develop --graph ? Are they pointing to the same commit?

Everything is working just fine. This appears to be a misunderstanding:

I could see the differences. Now how should I bring those changes from release to develop and why is bitbucket not able to catch those changes?

It's possible for two branches to have differences, and also for one to be fully up to date with the other. The scenario you are in is that develop is ahead of release. In other words, the commit release is currently pointing to is already in the history of develop, and there are more commits on develop that aren't in release yet.
Examples of develop ahead of release:
Z (develop)
|
Y
|\
X \
|  R (release)
W  |
|  Q
|  |
...

Z (develop)
|
Y
|
X (release)
|
W
|
...

So if you try to merge release into develop you can't, because it's already up to date. But you can merge develop into release, if you wanted to.
Without a branch getting reset or rewritten, I can think of two ways you could have ended up in this situation:

Perhaps you already merged release into develop. (Top commit graph example above.)
Maybe you created the release branch off of an older version of develop, and never added new commits to release since then. (Bottom commit graph example above.)

Update based on new information in the comments:

On further analysis I found release was merged into develop but without changes using ours strategy ... There were lot of files added/changed since then. Now I want to bring those missed changes into develop.

You are in situation 1 above (already merged), and this explains why you can't find the changes in release, on the develop branch. When you use git merge -s ours you're instructing Git to merge in the history without taking any of the changes. Since it appears that a lot has happened since then and you don't wish to rewrite history, one thing you can do is to make a new commit with all the changes that were on release which were "ignored" by the merge:
# 1. Identify the (-s ours) merge commit on develop with parents being:
#    the old develop, and release. (Let's call this MC)

# 2. Now find the merge-base of MC's two parents:
git merge-base MC^1 MC^2 # Let's call the output of this: MB

# 3. Now create a new temp branch from release
git checkout -b release-temp release

# 4. Now soft reset to the merge-base commit from above (MB)
git reset --soft MB

# 5. Now all of the changes on release are ready to be committed
git commit -m "Squash release into 1 commit from develop's POV"

# 6. Checkout develop
git checkout develop

# 7. Re-merge in the changes from release
git merge release-temp

Tip: if you're struggling to find the merge commit that brought in release (step #1 above), I have an alias that I use to help with this (and I use this daily on a fairly large repo). You can add this alias to your personal .gitconfig file:
[alias]
    find-first-merge = "!f() { \
        git log $1..$2 --pretty=format:'%h %ad %an %s' --ancestry-path --merges | tail -1; \
      }; f"

And then to use it:
git find-first-merge release develop

# or if develop is already checked out:

git find-first-merge release

You can also substitute a commit ID instead of a branch name. (In your case you have release pointing to the commit in question, but that's probably not normally the case.)
The output of that command will start with the commit ID of the merge commit that you need to revert.

I might have misunderstood, but in the comments AWS_beginner and mkrieger1 already tried to see if a merge in the opposite direction would show some changes. Both release <- develop and develop <- release say that the branch is up to date.

@dani-vta oh wow. Somehow I missed that. In that case this answer is probably not relevant. I will probably delete it shortly.

@dani-vta on further thought. I'm not sure I even believe it. It can't be the case that a PR in both directions is up to date, and git diff has differences. One of those must be wrong.

yeah I agree with you. I don't know how it's possible to have difference between two branches but also no difference when merging. My only thought was that he's probably doing git diff on his local branches (which have local changes), while the remote branches are up to date with each other, but they also cleared out that case. So I don't really know what could be :/

@TT I have asked bitbucket support team to clear the caches and now i can differences when i create PR from develop to release.But there are hell lot of changes what would be the simplest and cleanest way to merge and bring changes from release to develop here.

@AWS_Beginner What is leading you to believe that there are changes on release that aren't on develop? Also, does one of the git log --graph scenarios from this answer (example 1 or 2) apply to you?

@TTT I know because i have identified atleast 5 files which are  present in release but not in develop

@AWS_Beginner Try creating a temp branch off of release, confirm that those files exist, then merge in develop (and note if it is a fast-forward merge or not), and after the merge, check if the files were deleted.

@TTT when i create tmp branch from release again i am not able to create pull request for same reason.Also when tried to run git merge tmp it again saying already upto date

@AWS_Beginner That is consistent with what happened in the question, but that's not actually what I asked you to do. ;) I'm trying to help you determine why those files seem to be missing on develop. So: git switch -c temp release (you should see the files). Then, git merge develop (I think it will be fast-forward so confirm this is true, but more importantly, do you still see the files now after this merge or were they deleted?)

@TTT git switch was not supported in the git version my org has so i did git checkout release then git checkout -b temp then git merge develop  .It was fast forward merge but all the files and changes were deleted.

@AWS_Beginner That's great info! So that means the premise of your question is slightly flawed: "I know [that there are changes on release that aren't on develop] because i have identified atleast 5 files which are present in release but not in develop". It turns out, release is fully merged into develop, and you have commits on develop after the release branch that deleted some of the files you are expecting to see. If you can identify the problem commits on the develop branch, you can possibly revert them.

@TTT On further analysis i found release was merged with develop but without changes using ours strategy a script was running which was doing merge commits but actual files were not changed. Due to this lot of  changes were missed but the commits are present. There were lot of files added/changed since then.Now i want to bring those missed changes in my develop.Identifying individual commits are difficult because some changes were merged manually and changes reflecting but other done through script hence changes are missing but commit hash are present.

@AWS_Beginner Bingo! That explains the motivation for your question. Merging with -s ours should be done with care, because it can lead to a lot of confusion in the future. I have updated my answer based on this new information, with some steps that will help you re-merge in release again.

@TTT Thanks for this. But here problem is there are many such commits which were merged without the actual changes (using ours strategy as mentioned above) not just one single.

@AWS_Beginner Are all of the merges that were done with -s ours separate merges of the release branch at various times? If yes, then you can skip steps 1 and 2 and manually look back on the release branch until you find the oldest commit that was actually merged in. Set that commit ID to MB for the rest of the steps, and then you'll be able to merge in all of it. (Side note, do you know why those merges were done with -s ours? This is not something that someone would do without a good reason.)

@TTT The actual problem is intermittently some developers forgot to merge the release branch into develop. And then there is job which does this  -s ours merge automatically after release is deploy in prod (i guess that time they assumed that release will be merged with develop by developers).The developers were taking pull from latest release branch since they know the develop branch code is not upto date.But now to follow best practice we need to bring all changes from release to develop.

@AWS_Beginner It's unfortunate that job has been doing that multiple times. I can't think of any reason for that job to do that, and until you know a good reason for it, I'd turn that job off. If you're lucky enough that release has never been merged into develop since that started happening, then you could use my previous comment to recover. But if you have some merges of release with -s ours and some without, followed by more with it, this might be harder, but I would try it regardless.

@AWS_Beginner depending on what branching strategy you're using and what the relationship is between develop and release, you might want to consider throwing in the towel and calling release the source of truth, archiving off your current develop and then hard resetting it to release for a fresh start. (Again, whether or not this makes sense highly depends on what your branching strategy is...)

@TTT hard resetting it to release for a fresh start - does this mean hard reset develop and then try merge with release.

@AWS_Beginner if you hard reset develop, you're basically deleting it and making it identical to release. At that point no merging would be needed since they are the same. This is kind of a last resort if develop doesn't have much value anymore, but I'd still archive it with another branch in case you ever want it back. (Again this is highly dependent on how you use develop.)

@TTT But i am still confused how to bring all changes from my release to develop in this case. Going forward i want feature to be created from develop.
